# How to resolve this "IndentationError: unexpected indent" error?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

Used this code from http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html

```py
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers() layer_list = [] for layer in layers:
    layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
```

and getting this error after reloading

```py
IndentationError: unexpected indent 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/vedan/.qgis2/python/plugins\SaveAttributes\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .save_attributes import SaveAttributes
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/vedan/.qgis2/python/plugins\SaveAttributes\save_attributes.py", line 185
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
   ^
```

Using QGis 2.18.3

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Can you confirm your code looks like the snippet you've pasted above?  To me it looks like the first line should be split into 3 lines.

Answer (score 3):

In Python you need to make sure your indentation is consistent. [The Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17) prescribes using 4 spaces for indentation:

```
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer_list = []
# indent the contents of the for loop 4 spaces ea: 
for layer in layers:
    layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)

# now that the for loop is done return to previous indent level
```

Be careful copy-pasting code, and be aware what kind of tabs your text editor uses. If you use something like gedit (Linux) or notepad++ (windows) you can set the tab to be 4 spaces each instead of a tab character.

Comment: Is this issue could be becoz of the fact that i am using the 32 bit of OSGEO4W on a X64 WINDOWS PC ?

Comment: Nope, Python requires consistent indentation no matter what your OS / OSGEO version is. This is a basic standard in Python. I would recommend reviewing some basic Python tutorials (not GIS specific, just Python).